# Apex Metadata API limits

Tags: apex, metadata-api

Does a call to Metadata.Operations.retrieve via Apex count towards the API limit?
We are dynamically getting page layout via metadata API in Apex to build a custom UI in lwc. Couldn't find any documentation regarding limits on this. Has anyone come across any limits related to this?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but: that's literally what the UI API is for. It provides much richer data than the Apex Metadata API. Have you considered using the UI API instead?

Comment: @DavidReed getRecordUi is deprecated  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: The underlying UI API resource is not deprecated. Just the wire adapter.

Comment: @DavidReed calling UI API would have to be done via REST API callout, I am correct? That would definitely count towards API limit? Or am I missing something?